# Are Questions about Oil on Topic

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I am thinking that questions about oil should be on topic for Personal Finance and Money because it is related to investing. Do I have that right?

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on the question itself. As long as you're asking about it from the point of view of personal finance (rather than say economics), and you're not looking for specific recommendations (e.g. where can I buy oil, should I buy oil, etc), it's probably ok. But take a look through the [help centre](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first to make sure.